# How should I do this in django

Tags: python, django

I was thinking about making a Hostel Allocation Web application. It has models, Student, Room, Hostel. What I want is to create a function that allocates students after each year. For that, I thought in the student view each student after completing his four years of stay can click on vacate hostel after completing his degree, and for others, I want to create something that allocates them, 
Now there are certain constraints, there are Undergraduate students with degree period 4 years and each year has access to different types of rooms, First-year triple sharing, second and third-year double sharing and fourth-year single rooms. Also, a Hostel has Ph.D. students as well but their stay period is not defined.

So, what I was thinking is that First years should be allotted by uploading a CSV file and I have made that part, So the next part is to allot subsequent years based on their preferences, So how could I make something like this in Django that allows them to make it based on their preference, I was thinking each student would be given a unique token, and while filling for rooms one student can do for a room, and that token needs to be entered. Is this the right way or should I do something else. I am a newbie please suggest me a good way to do this.

models.py

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 40,help_text = "Name of the student")
    entry_number = models.CharField(max_length = 11,help_text = "Entry Number of a student")
    hostel_name = models.ForeignKey('Hostel', on_delete = models.SET_NULL,null = True)
    room = models.ForeignKey('Room',on_delete = models.SET_NULL,null = True)
    CHOICES = (
        ('m','Male'),
        ('f','Female'),
        ('e','Engaged'),
    )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=CHOICES)
    def __str__(self):
       return '%s, %s' % (self.name,self.entry_number)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('student-detail',args=[str(self.id)])
    class Meta:
        verbose_name="Student Record"


class Hostel(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length= 15)
    locality= models.URLField(max_length= 200, blank= True, default='',help_text='Google maps URL of the hostel')
    total_rooms= models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, blank =True)
    CHOICES = (
        ('m', 'Male'),
        ('f', 'Female'),
        ('e', 'Engaged'),
    )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CHOICES, verbose_name=_('Type of Hostel'), help_text='Either Boys/Girls or Married students Hostel')
    def __str__(self):
        return  self.name
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('hostel-detail',args=[str(self.id)])
    class Meta:
        verbose_name="Hostel Record"


class Room(models.Model):
    hostel= models.ForeignKey(Hostel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name= models.CharField(max_length = 5)
    floor= models.CharField(max_length = 1, blank=True)
    wing= models.CharField(max_length = 1, blank=True)
    comment= models.CharField(max_length = 100,blank=True, default = "comment here")
    room_capacity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(3),])
    room_accomodation= models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('room-detail',args=[str(self.id)])
    class Meta:
        verbose_name="Room Record"
```